# Plot a line chart in Excel with multiple lines

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, charts

Let's say I have a data table like

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ Stock  ║   Date   ║ Price ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ Stock1 ║ 1/1/2017 ║  17.0 ║
║ Stock1 ║ 1/2/2017 ║  17.4 ║
║ Stock1 ║ 1/3/2017 ║  16.9 ║
║ Stock2 ║ 1/1/2017 ║  78.9 ║
║ Stock2 ║ 1/2/2017 ║  77.4 ║
║ Stock2 ║ 1/3/2017 ║  79.3 ║
║ Stock3 ║ 1/1/2017 ║ 130.6 ║
║ Stock3 ║ 1/2/2017 ║ 128.5 ║
║ Stock3 ║ 1/3/2017 ║ 124.7 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

I want to use Excel to draw one single line chart, x-axis should be the dates, y-axis should be the value of stocks. And each stock has its own line in the chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Convert your data to an Excel Table.
2) Create a Pivot Table based upon your data table from Step 1, with:
    column (legend/series) labels = Stock
    row (axis/categories) labels = Date
    values = Price
3) Create a Line Pivot Chart from your data

[image]

Comment: In the pivot table how do you set "values = Price"? I have Excel 2013, I only can have Sum, Count, Average, Max, Min, Product, Count Numbers, StdDev, StdDevp, Var, Varp to calculate values. The next tab "Show Values As" seems to calculate %.

Comment: Assuming one value (price) for each row (date/stock combination), Sum, Average, Max, and Min will all return the same value, so you can select any of them and it will work.  If you have more than one price (e.g. opening and closing), you can either aggregate using one of the above values, or create additional rows by adding another variable (e.g. date/time/stock or price type), and then aggregate the new single value.

Answer (score 0):

Put all Stock data in separate columns, select the whole table and
create `X-Y` chart as usual:

[image]

Comment: If I have many stocks, it is a huge manual work to pull them to separated columns. Any convenient way?

Comment: @hardywang: sure, but this is important condition you should mention in the question.
How many? Also, is the dates (`x`-readings) are the same for all stocks, as in the example? 
We can use a worksheet function to reorganize the data.